# Cells are treated as text after input from file

Tags: excel, vba

I create a script in VBA that copy data from txt to spreadsheet, but cells are treated like a text even after formatting them to percent or number:

```
Sub PasteTextFileContent()
Dim wbExcel As Workbook, wbText As Workbook
Dim wsExcel As Worksheet
Set wbExcel = ThisWorkbook
Set wsExcel = wbExcel.Sheets("PastData")
Set wbText = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\test.txt")

wbText.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy wsExcel.Cells

wbText.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Sheets("PastData").Visible = True
    Sheets("PastData").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
    Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1 _
    ), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Sheets("PastData").Visible = False
End Sub
```

I input data to text with:

```
Sub ToTxtFileSimpleButWorkingWell()
Dim strFile_Path As String
strFile_Path = "C:\Test\test.txt"
Open strFile_Path For Append As #1
Write #1, Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"), Sheets("DASHBOARD").Range("V1").Value, Sheets("DASHBOARD").Range("V2").Value, Sheets("DASHBOARD").Range("V3").Value, Sheets("DASHBOARD").Range("V4").Value, Sheets("DASHBOARD").Range("V5").Value, Sheets("DASHBOARD").Range("V6").Value, Sheets("DASHBOARD").Range("V7").Value
Close #1
End Sub
```

[image]

How can I change that?

Comment: I guess your decimal separator is a comma, so you will need to replace the dots with commas. Sidenote: The ones (1) of the second element of each of the arrays are indicating that you have imported everything using the `General` format.

Comment: Yeah it seems you are right I swith to diffrent PC, and decimal numbers were separate by comma not a dot. I can't even think how i will struggle if you didn't mention that. Thank you.